# How to ask the user to enter the desired day of the week?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need the user to enter a number from 1-7 for the starting day of the week: Sun=1, Mon=2, etc.  How should I word this?  My program code is below.

```
wkday = ("Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat")
daysInMonth = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
y = int(input("Start Day: "))
f = 2*(13) + (3*(13+1)//5) + (y-1) + ((y-1)//4) - ((y-1)//100) + ((y-1)//400) + 2
count = (f % 7) - 1
if((y%4 == 0 and y%100 != 0) or y%400 == 0):
        daysInMonth[1]=29
else:
        daysInMonth[1]=28

zip(month[:], daysInMonth[:])
for m, dim in zip(month[:], daysInMonth[:]):
    print('\n')
    print(m)
    for wk in wkday[:]:
        print(wk, end)    
        print()
    tab=0
    while tab<=count:
        print('\t', end)
        tab+=1
    for d in range(1,dim+1):
        count+=1
        if count == 7:
            print()
            count = 0
        print(d, ""'\t')
```

Comment: what do you mean by only to enter the 1?

Comment: If you just want to print out the calendar of a year, use module `calendar`.

Comment: To test for a leap year you can use function `isleap(year)` from module `calendar`.

Comment: Very simply:

print "Please enter the day of the week on which the year starts: \
1 for Sun, 2 for Mon, ... 7 for Sat."

Place this just ahead of your input statement.